# How can I tell if an STL model will need supports?

Tags: support-structures, stl, algorithm

How can I detect if a generated STL model will need to be printed with supports?

Context: I have a pipeline which parametrically generates OpenSCAD models, generates the STL, and sends them to the printer.  I would like to (a) automatically detect the cases where supports are necessary so that I can specify the appropriate flags to the slicer, and (b) attempt to rotate the generated model so that supports won't be necessary.

Comment: How do you define "needs support"? Is just turning on supports in the slicer and letting it add supports where it thinks is necessary not good enough?

Comment: You can always send the "use support" flag as the slicer will determine whether or not to use them.

Comment: Great suggestion to always turn on the "use support" flag.  I'll update the question to further explain my other use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to:

1. Slice with slicer (Cura in my case) with support enabled.
2. Search for text: *TYPE:SUPPORT*

   G0 F1800 X237.873 Y184.24
   G0 X233.869 Y183.237
   ;TYPE:SUPPORT
   G1 F1500 E562.81355
   G1 F900 X233.579 Y183.939 E562.91577
   G1 X233.368 Y184.67 E563.01816
3. If it exists, then try to call it again:
4. Use auto-orientation plugin to validate if there is a better (no support) model position.

As an alternative, you could scan the mesh and looks for an angle greater than 45 or 50 degrees.

Comment: I wonder where you got the idea ;-) . This is how I would solve it too.

Comment: It's easier than that:  load the STL into Cura and , in SolidView, regions requiring support will be colored red.

Comment: as long as scrip can handle that manual operation it is a good solution :) @CarlWitthoft